# Cannot understand the code I got after online JS compression

Tags: javascript

After applying online JS compression to a function I have the following:

```
t = function (e) {
    return ch = e.charAt(0), set = new Set, set.add("."), set.add("/"), set.add("\\"), !set.has(ch)
}
```

How is it possible to have so many instructions separated by comma  and what is
returning in the end? My JS reference says nothing about such syntax

Comment: what is the outcome? share it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center.

Comment: The original function just checked if the first char in param is one from the Set. But I used a traditonAL syntax

Comment: This code simply checks if first character of the passed parameter is one of these three characters or not `.` , `/`, or `\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma can be used to combine several statements into a single expression. In short, it means "evaluate all of these statements and then return the value of the last statement".

The code above gets the first character of the string passed, builds a `Set` with several characters in it, and then checks to see if the first character is in the `Set` (and returns the value of that check). It's the equivalent of:

```
t = function(e) {
  ch = e.charAt(0);
  set = new Set;
  set.add('.');
  set.add('/');
  set.add('\\');
  return !set.has(ch);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I had before comression!! But is comma a new syntax? I mean my reference book is silent about it

Comment: I accept this answer. But it says I have to wait N mins

Comment: @JonasHaughland - Nope. Definitely not new. You can read the MDN documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator evaluates each instruction and the "return" command then returns only the last one (i.e. "!set.has(ch)")

So, it's a short of way of writing

```
t = function (e) {
  ch = e.charAt(0);
  set = new Set;
  set.add("."):
  set.add("/");
  set.add("\\");
  return !set.has(ch);
}
```

So basically what this does it returns true if (e) is neither ".", "/" nor "\"